# Help text in chatrooms' "access" tabs is inaccurate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

According to Jeff and Marc's comments on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/so-chat-why-is-it-that-only-members-of-stack-overflow-with-at-least-20-reputati/74100#74100), being on a chatroom's whitelist is no longer a guarantee that a user may talk in the room. Users must also meet the chat system's required minimum rep for talking — currently 20 — except for a brief window.

However, the "access" tab of room info pages in chat still reads

> Regardless of the room's general access setting **and their reputation**, these users will be able to talk in this room.

*(emphasis mine)*. This should be modified to describe the new settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is correct. If a user is in that list, they *can* talk, regardless of their reputation.

What has been restricted is the ability of the room owner to *add* users to that list; only moderators can do this now for users not meeting the minimum requirement.

This probably isn't the last word in this; Jeff's 4-hour thingadongdong isn't implemented yet (note that nobody said otherwise), so the rules are subject to change.

But *currently*, the text is, in fact, true.