# Why can't new users chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO Chat: Why is it that “Only members of Stack Overflow with at least 20 reputation may talk…”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/so-chat-why-is-it-that-only-members-of-stack-overflow-with-at-least-20-reputat)

I was having a comment discussion with a new user.  When I went to move the discussion to chat, it told me that the user needed to have 20 rep.  Why?  Doesn't it seem like new users could benefit from the ability to chat with older users?

Comment: Ever hear about spam bots?

Comment: As Oded says, it's mainly one ring of protection against spam. Seeing as there's thousands of new users to the site, it's simply a necessary thing to have, even though it is very inconvenient for some.

Comment: The bar is *extremely* low too.

Comment: @Servy : It's true that the bar is low, but I suspect this is the first question that the user is posting on the site.  If the purpose is to protect against spam, perhaps only allowing a new user to chat if a higher rep user initiate it would be a better solution.  It just seems a little stupid that SO suggests I move the "conversation" to a chat and then doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: @Oded -- I can't tag multiple users in a comment, but the comment above to Servy was also in response to your comment about spam.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291/167443

Comment: "New SO user" doesn't necessarily mean "new to programming and needs hand-holding". There are many users with 1000 and 2000 reputation who gained that just from asking great questions, and I'm sure they benefit from chat, which is a privilege earned from demonstrating an understanding of how Stack Exchange works.