# new users without rep to chat

Tags: discussion, chat, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO Chat: Why is it that “Only members of Stack Overflow with at least 20 reputation may talk…”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/so-chat-why-is-it-that-only-members-of-stack-overflow-with-at-least-20-reputat)

Related question: [Random distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757566/random-distribution/11757840#)

I helped a new user, who declared that he was a novice and asked for some specific help in the comments. I would have been happy to walk him through it but he did not have the required 20 rep to chat. Even having upvoted his question myself he only has/had 11 rep.

Is there a reason we limit chat to those >20 rep? The other option is I have a long, difficult conversation with this person over comments, which is not great, and exactly why chat is useful in the first place.